# How to print in rails after a create api is called from an android

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, printing

I have an android app and a rails app. When a order is made from android, it calls create order API in rails app. So whenever a create order is successful in rails app,i want to perform a print action that prints the order bill using the data send from the android.

But the controller i created only gives a response either in json or html format. i.e

```rb
class API::V1::OrdersController << Api::ApiController
  def create
    @order = Order.create(
                    item: params[:item],
                    quantity: params[:quantity],
                    price: params[:price]
                    )
    if @order.persisted?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { notice: 'Order successfully created.' }
        format.html { render :print }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This will only give back the response of 'Order successfully created.' when json is used or the html format page written in 'print.html.slim' to the android. 
But i want to print a order bill page from 'print.html.slim' when a order is persisted.

`print.html.slim`

```
table.table
  thead
    th Item Name
    th Quantity
    th Price
  tbody
    tr
      td = @order.item
      td = @order.quantity
      td = @order.price
```

Is there any way i can do this ?

Comment: You could check out https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf to create a pdf from the results

Comment: Is the printer hooked up to the Rails serving computer? If so, you'll likely want to shell out to `lp` or some other command-line printing utility with a printable file. If not, you'll likely need to poll the server for "ready to print" jobs, lock the job so that other printers don't print simultaneously, then pull the print file and print on the client computer that actually has a printer attached.

Comment: @Unixmonkey can't you just send a IPP request from the rails app to Cups (provided cups is installed) on the print server? Seems a lot easier than shelling out.

Comment: This question is far too vague to actually be answerable. What does "print the order" actually entail? Do you want to give the user a printable order confirmation? Do you want to print out a an order on paper on mail at the place that receives the order?  In that case the simplest solution may be to send an email with a PDF from rails to the shop and they setup a daemon which prints it out when the emails are received. That makes the actual hardware setup issues the clients problem and not your problem and avoids any coupling.

Answer (score 0):

What you have and what you seek are two different things.

Since you have set up your Rails server as an API end point, you can only return JSON values. For what you need, you should accept the JSON data in your android app and do what you wish with the data in your app (like displaying the confirmed order)